# enable checkbox with id only

Tags: html, mechanize, python-2.6

I want to fill a HTML form, I am using mechanize module of python.
my HTML code is like that for checkbox and dropdown is :

```
<div id="post_cd">
<input role="checkbox" id="cd_info" class="cbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="s-iso" style="display:none"></div>


<label for="type" id="cdtype" class="cd" style="width:60px;margin:1px;float:left;text-align:right;">CD type:</label>
<select id='cdtype' class=" ui-iso" style="width:100px;margin:1px;float:left;">
                <option value="CD1">Error1</option>
                <option value="CD2">Error1</option>
                <option value="CD3">Error2</option>
             </select>
```

I have tried with following but getting errors:

for checkbox:   `form.find_control("cd_info").items[0].selected = True`
for dropdown:    `form['cdtype']= ['Error1']`

error:

```
    raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching "+description)
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'cd_info'

    raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching "+description)
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'cdtype'
```

Comment: Any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<form>` in your HTML code. So probably `form` is not pointing to an element around the HTML code you provide at the moment you call `find_control` or the subscription operator.

You can try to print the text of the form to be sure you are looking at the right thing:

```
print form
```